# Why did google choose C/S architecture in android camera?

Tags: android, camera, android-binder

As we know , android camera is the C/S architecture, including the client and the service. They communicate each other by the Binder. They are running in different process.

So I have a question : why android camera have a client and service ? What's the advantage?

Comment: Probably Client=Hardware camera & Server=Service to access Client...

Comment: @Raynold In fact, App.Camera-->Frameworks.Camera -->Jni--> Client --> Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be they choosed C/S architecture, because it is better for sending notifications to listeners, for example Dropbox and Google+ app are listening for photo events for uploading new photos to cloud. Also, you can subscribe your app for same events too (with [`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)). So, they not watching for changes in DCIM folders, they subscribe to system events.

With just client arhitecture, photo apps will have implement sending of all [`camera events`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) 
to provide compatibility to other apps.

But it is just my opinion :)